# Limpar Modal com Button Sem Gravar Dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Possuo um modal onde utilizo o mesmo para inclusão e alteração dos dados.

Verifico se o campo `txtid` está preenchido. Se tiver é alteração, senão inclusão.

Para preencher os campos o usuário precisa selecionar a linha do grid, onde o id é resgatado para fazer a alteração.

Porém preciso limpar o modal se o usuário não fizer a alteração.

Criei um botão que atualiza o grid, perde a seleção e limpa o txt, porém ele abre com os campos todos preenchidos.

```
GridAgenda();
GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
txtid.Text = "";
```

`GridAgenda()` é o método que carrega o GridView.

As vezes ele seleciona e não altera, clico neste botão para limpar, e clico no cadastrar, o modal vem preenchido com a última linha selecionada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer o jquery fazer este trabalho para você, caso não queira trabalhar no code behind.

Coloque nos campos ao qual você deseja limpar alguma classe para o jquery identificar mais tarde, ex: `CssClass="limpar"`.

Pronto, agora você vai fazer no click de fechar o modal a ação de limpar os campos:

```
<button type="button" id="btnFechar" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
```

E criar uma função em jquery para executar tudo isto:

```
<script>
     $(function (){
        $("#btnFechar").click(function (){
             $( ".limpar" ).each(function() {
                  $(".limpar").val("");
             });
        });
     });
<script>
```

Sempre que o usuário clicar no botão fechar da modal, os campos serão limpos.